# PHP preg_replace last N characters if non alphanumeric

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove last N characters from string if these characters are non alpha numeric strings.

For example:

- `TEST.` -> `TEST`
- `TEST2.-` -> `TEST2`
- `TEST_3.,/` -> `TEST_3`

I was able to achieve that with the following regular expression but it only works for last last character (works for example 1 above). How to check if more then just a last character matches the case...

```
/[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]$/
```

Comment: Perhaps, you are just missing a quantifier: `/[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]+$/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juat add `+` next to the character class, so that it would match one or more (*non alphanumeric or : or space*) characters exists at the last.

```
preg_replace('~[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]+$~', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
/[^a-zA-Z\d]{1,3}$/g
```

{1,3}$ - is the range of how many characters at the end of the string must not be non-alphanumeric